# ODP.net : Invalid Username/Password

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, odp.net

Why are the quotes around `USER ID` value (see second), causing the connection to return

> invalid username/password.

1. `DATA SOURCE=host:port/database;USER ID=user$name;Password=password (works)`
2. `DATA SOURCE=host:port/database;USER ID="user$name";Password=password (fails)`

**ODAC for VS 2017 18.3.0.0.0**

Comment: Hi Haywood, welcome to StackOverflow! Is the ODAC VS 2017 18.3.0.0.0 the version of your Oracle database?

Comment: Please provide more information to perform a good question. I recommend you reading the StackOverflow publishing guide lines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Its got to simply be invalid syntax for this type of connection string.  If #1 works, why bother with 2?

Comment: I'm unable to connect to Oracle via Visual Studio 2017 Oracle Developer Tools extension. The extension is producing a connection string that looks like #1, where the username has surrounding parenthesis when the username has special characters. I want to understand if this is a bug.